# How to add and delete contacts to nox vb.net

Tags: android, vb.net, android-emulator

I have vcf file or txt include numbers. I want to add this numbers to nox android emulator and delete it by vb.net or c#

to explain more: I have form with 2 buttons

button 1 will add contacts automatically to nox android emulator

button 2 will delete all contacts in nox android emulator

Comment: I would use a third button to make your question more clear and to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you post your errors as text through editing this question?